# Compress Image in Swift without losing background transparency

Tags: swift, image, compression, png, jpeg

i am looking for a way to compress images with background transparency. I already know about UIImageJPEGRepresentation(FILE, CompressionLevel). With this snippet I reach my wished compressed file size (<100Kb (image quality is not that important)) but I lose my background transparency.

Does anyone of you guys know how to compress an image without losing its transparency?

if this helps in any way: I need to convert the image to data format anyways for certain actions and calculation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert an image to a 16bit color image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801970/convert-an-image-to-a-16bit-color-image)

Comment: JPEG doesn't support transparency, instead, you need to use PNG

Comment: I am living same problem, @MadProgrammer We know jpeg doesn't support transparency but UIImagePNGRepresentation method is not compress the PNG images. Question is "How to compress PNG images without losing bg transparency"

Comment: Png does compress the image (try writing the data out manually, it’s even better the putting it through a zip stream), it’s just not as good as jpg

Comment: did you able to solve this problem?